# How to auto complete like CSH when using ZSH (prefix ↑)

Tags: zsh

When using `zsh` how could I auto-complete like `csh`, for example, having this history:

```
 9994  vim bar
 9995  git add .
 9996  git commit -am "test..."
 9997  ssh 10.1.2.3
 9998  ls
 9999  vim foo
```

In `csh` if I type:

git <kbd>↑</kbd>

It will auto-complete with:

```
git commit -am "test..."
```

If I presss arrow up again <kbd>↑</kbd> it auto-completes with

```
git add .
```

for example, if I want to edit the previous file I was using, I can just type:

vim <kbd>↑</kbd>

That will auto-complete with `vim foo`, If I press 2 times the <kbd>↑</kbd>:

vim <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>

It will autocomplete to:

```
vim bar
```

Personally, I found it extremely easy compared to the `bash` reverse search `<ctrl-R>` since I just have to prefix the command, press arrow key up, and done, because of this I would like to know-how in `ZSH` I could achieve the same, currently, as an extra, I am using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) but there are cases where I just need use the previous command instead of searching, maybe `fzf` could be configured to work the same any ideas?